# File upload via iFrame

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, file, iframe

we're creating a web page and I have to manage the file upload stuff.
I am using an iframe for the file upload. But actually I don't know what happens when using this. On server side we're using Java.
This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#formsubmit").click(function () {

        var iframe = $('<iframe name="postiframe" id="postiframe"></iframe>');

        $("body").append(iframe);

        var form = $('#theuploadform');
        form.attr("action", "http://localhost:13000/auth/login");
        form.attr("method", "post");

        form.attr("encoding", "multipart/form-data");
        form.attr("enctype", "multipart/form-data");

        form.attr("target", "postiframe");
        form.attr("file", $('#userfile').val());
        form.submit();

        $("#postiframe").load(function () {
          var   iframeContents = this.contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
            $("#textarea").html(iframeContents);
        });

        return false;

    });

});
```

(I copied the code from the internet, but I don't understand it.)

Can anyone tell me what happens when clicking the submit button? What is being send? The file as bytes? As I want to write our server-side java handler I need to understand this.
I think I've spent too much time for trying to understand this.

First I thought we could send the file via jQuerys POST method as it worked for the user authentication. But it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For backend you need controller to catch http request and a java class with attribute :

say your java class is named File.java

```
private List<MultipartFile> file;
String saveDirectory = System.getProperty("catalina.home");
    List<MultipartFile> ListaFajlova = File.getFile();
    List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (null != ListaFajlova && ListaFajlova.size() > 0) {
        for (MultipartFile multipartFile : ListaFajlova) {

            String fileName = multipartFile.getOriginalFilename();
            if (!"".equalsIgnoreCase(fileName)) {            
                multipartFile
                        .transferTo(new File(saveDirectory + File.separator+fileName));
                fileNames.add(fileName);
            }
        }
    }
```

This way you save files in your saveDirectory and you get list of filenames you save in db for easier access.

Hope this helps.